# C# local arrays IReadOnlyCollection/IReadOnlyList optimizing away object creation

Tags: c#, readonly

Do the following three methods have equivalent garbage collection behavior? #1 would be a stretch, but is today's C# compiler smart enough to optimize away the object creation in #2 on every invocation of the method? I specifically do not want to hoist the array initialization outside of the method.

```
    public Boolean IsRgb1(string color)
    {
        string[] colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
        return colors.Contains(color);
    }

    public Boolean IsRgb2(string color)
    {
        IReadOnlyCollection<string> colors = new[] { "red", "green", "blue" };
        return colors.Contains(color);
    }

    public Boolean IsRgb3(string color)
    {
        switch(color)
        {
            case "red":
            case "green":
            case "blue":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no compiler magic that occurs relating to these types. An array is *always* created in both Rgb1 and Rgb2, on each invocation.

The array declaration shorthand syntax

```
string[] colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
```

is the same as (showing the 'deduced syntax')

```
string[] colors = new string[3] { "red", "green", "blue" };
```

The basic rule is: `new` *always* creates a new object/instance. To create the (array) object only once, only create it once. The single array instance could then be shared using a member/field. This 'hoisting' must be *manually* done.

```
// One array created and stored for later use ..
private static string[] Colors = { "red", "green", "blue" };
// .. independent of number of times this method is called
public Boolean IsRgb(string color)
{
    return Colors.Contains(color);
}
```

In both cases the Contains is from `IEnumerable<T>` as both `T[]` and `IReadOnlyList<T>` are subtypes of IEnumerable<sup>1</sup> and eligible for the LINQ Contains extension method. The same IEnumerable Contains implementation (LINQ To Objects) will be used and any specialization that is applied to arrays should apply to both cases.

The Rgb3 case avoids the array creation entirely and it avoids some method calls and it avoids overhead of doing the generalized collection Contains 'looping' logic. It will be the fastest - if/where such matters - simply because it has the least to do.

A simple switch statement for strings can be considered an alternative way of writing a series of `if..else if..` comparing the same value. In this case there is *no* new object creation per method call: the string literals have been interned and there is clearly no new array.

Alternatively, consider simply using a single expression:

```
 return color == "red" || color == "green" || color == "blue";
```

<sup>1</sup>Because the type inheritance is confusing, here is a small extract:

```
T[] -> IEnumerable<T> (Contains as Extension Method)
    -> IList<T> -> ICollection<T> (Contains in Interface) -> IEnumerable<T>
    -> IReadOnlyList<T> -> IEnumerable<T>
                        -> IReadOnlyCollection<T> -> IEnumerable<T>
```

Since `T[]` is a subtype of `IReadOnlyList<T>` the assignment in Rgb2 resulted in an implicit upcast - the variable still names the newly created array object. The selection of `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` happens at compile-time and thus both Rgb1 and Rgb2 methods will use the extension method `IEnumerable<T>.Contains` on the original created array object. To use the `ICollection<T>.Contains` would require `((IList<string>)colors).Contains(..)` or similar.

Comment: In this case, I'd probably opt for `new Hashset<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`; fast lookup with a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: @MetroSmurf The string comparisons will be faster (and even the contains might be faster) due to a much smaller constant overhead.

Comment: Agreed for the small amount of data. For larger sets, Hashset. Anyhow, just another option.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Definitely; for a 'normal sized' palette of color names that would be a worthwhile consideration! It is also often easier to add to a collection, which is designed to allow an arbitrary size.

Comment: @MetroSmurf For larger sets, no, you probably still don't need to bother with a hash set. If a switch statement has sufficient case labels that performance will improve, the compiler will already generate and call a hash function behind the scenes. Try it yourself.

Comment: @hvd Interesting - I wasn't aware of that switch behavior. Little wonders. From a style/preference choice, I'd probably place the 'configuration' in a collection outside of the method.